# signalr client doesn't fire on click listener

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

The process is : When the `.post-thread` is clicked, it calls the server through the hub, returns a `<p data-id = id class = 'take-thread'>`, and appends on `foo` div. Then I click the `<p>`, it should run `TakeThread` at server side.

However, when I click on the newly appended `<p>`, `console.log('test')` doesn't fire until I added the code in the star rectangle. I don't understand why. There is already a listener in the `Hub.start().done()` to trigger the click. Why do I have to do it in the hub client function ?

JS:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
chat.client.updateThings(id){
   $('.foo').append('<p data-id = "id" class = "take-thread"></p>');

   // Why do I need to these code below?  
   ************************************************  
   * $('.take-thread').on('click', function () {  *
   *     console.log("test");                     *   
   *     chat.server.takeThread("blah...");       * 
   * });                                          * 
   ************************************************

}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('.post-thread').on('click', function () {
        chat.server.postThread("Test"); // works
    });
    $('.take-thread').on('click', function () {
        console.log("test");
        chat.server.takeThread("blah..."); 
    });
}
```

C# Hub:

```
public void PostThread(string title) {
    var id = someCalculation();
    Clients.All.updateThings(id);
}

public void TakeThread(string title) {
    // do things
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a binding problem. Dynamic elements added to the page after document.ready is called do not automatically get rebound. This is what you were doing when you added the second on click event to the `updateThings` function.

You need to us [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) with a static parentSelector that is there on document.ready (`.foo`) together with a selector of your dynamic element being added by the SignalR callback (`.take-thread`).

See this example using standard alerts in place of SignalR: http://jsfiddle.net/kspearrin/0zyoqyxL/

In the end, your Javascript should be updated to the following:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
chat.client.updateThings(id){
   $('.foo').append('<p data-id="id" class="take-thread"></p>');
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('.post-thread').on('click', function () {
        chat.server.postThread("Test"); // works
    });

    $('.foo').on('click', '.take-thread', function () {
        console.log("test");
        chat.server.takeThread("blah..."); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't aware of the dynamic elements binding.